# How to create a role for a Discord Bot

Tags: python, bots, discord

I am using discord.py to create my bot and I was wondering how to create roles/permissions specific to the bot?

What that means is when the bot enters the server for the first time, it has predefined permissions and role set in place so the admin of the server doesn't need to set a role and permissions for the bot.

I have been trying to look up a reference implementation of this but no luck. If someone can point me at example of how to get a simple permission/role for a bot that will be great!

Comment: Use [`create_role`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.create_role) to create the role and [`add_roles`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.add_roles) to give it to the bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to do this through oath2 using the url parameters

Answer (score 1):

Bot will create it's own role when it joins the server through the invite. You can set the bot's role permissions in OAuth2. Just click this [link](https://discordapp.com/developers/applications/) and select your application. Then go to OAuth2 (or create a bot if u didn't) and select all permissions which your bot's role will have. Then copy the URL (which will be your bot's invite). Invite your bot. Done!

Answer (score 0):

> you want to do this through oath2 using the url parameters

As [Astrydax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48163714/8582663) said, the bot will automatically create its own role upon invite, and you can invite you bot here: [Discord Developers](https://discord.com/developers/applications/me)